# transfer data from a gridview to a database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code

```
private void BindSecondaryGrid()
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["SelectedRecords1"];
    gridview3.DataSource = dt;
    gridview3.DataBind(); 
}
```

The selected records from the `gridview2` are saved there `ViewState["SelectedRecords1"]`.The columns are **id, name, quantity, total**.
Then these records are saved in `gridview3` with

```
gridview3.DataSource = dt;
gridview3.DataBind();
```

Now i would like to get these values from gridview3 and store them in a table in my database with same columns of course.Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Is the question about "how to get to the data" or "how to write to DB"?

I'll try with "how to get to the data" :-)

You can loop the rows of "dt" using:

```
foreach(DataRow oRow in dt.Rows)
{
  int id = Convert.ToInt32(oRow["id"]);
  string name = oRow["name"].ToString();
  int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(oRow["quantity"]);
  int total = Convert.ToInt32(oRow["total"]);
}
```

Then you need to setup a DB connection and add the values.